# Can't install older version 1.8.27 of Geth on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get install ethereum

sudo apt-get install ethereum=VERSION
```

And

```
sudo apt-get upgrade ethereum
```

To install a specific version of Geth but I can't.

Answer (score 2):

An older version of Geth can be installed using tar file, here I am using version 1.8.16. To download the required Geth file, we need to check the OS version using the following command.

```
> dpkg --print-architecture   
amd64
```

Once you have your OS information, download (amd64 tar in our case) file from the Geth website.

Upload downloaded tar file on a server and extract using the following command:

```
sudo tar -xvf <filename>
```

In our case,

```
sudo tar -xvf  geth-linux-amd64-1.8.16-477eb093.tar.gz
```

Step into extracted folder

```
cd geth-linux-amd64-1.8.16-477eb093
```

It should contain the geth file, make it executable with the below command.

```
sudo chmod +x geth
```

Copy file to the user bin.

```
sudo cp geth /usr/local/bin/
```

Check the Geth version with the following command

```
> geth version  
Version: 1.8.16-stable
```

Geth is now installed successfully on the system

Ref: [How To Install Geth On A Linux Machine](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-install-geth-on-linux-machine)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the older versions from here:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases

To install ethereum on Ubuntu type the following commands into your CLI:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt update
```

Once this is done type:

```
sudo apt install ethereum
```

Comment: Thankyou for response, I have tried these commands but still the geth version is the latest 1.9.6 and I need to install 1.8.27.

Comment: Have you downloaded the older version from the github source?

Comment: yeah I did, but still the same version.